# Best way to display dynamic element on a QListView (with Model/View)?

Tags: qt

We can implement our own delegate to display rich text or images, but ListView can print static item only. You can't put "real" items into it, you can just paint them.

So, there isn't a way to show clickable hyperlink, ReTweet buttons, or load asynchronous images. Just think about **a timeline-listview for Facebook or Twitter**. That's what I'm working on.

Now, my solution is writing my listview in QML. Other widget are still native Qt widget. (I don't like a non-native pure QML user interface.)

QML is really flexible when doing that kind of work. Then export my model, finally put a viewer into my QMainWindow. But coding in two programming languages and trying to communicate with other native widget is really difficult.

So, what's the best way to display dynamic element?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic element, is it like a video or animation, that constantly changes even when you do nothing?

Comment: such as `QPushButton`.

Comment: So you want to have buttons in your list widget?

Comment: I want to put what QWidget can put.

Comment: OK, then see if my answer helps you. Is adding widgets what you want? By 'dynamic content' you mean widgets?

Comment: I found there is a Project called [Choquk](http://choqok.gnufolks.org/). I want a ListView like that. Is seems they use `ListWidget`. But I don't fully understand how did they do it.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code, and see?

Comment: I don't fully understand how did they do it after I read the source.

Comment: Then read it again, until you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MVC framework is not very good for this kind of work.

To do it properly, you would need to provide a delegate for whatever dynamic types you need to display, and then provide an external mechanism that forces the model to emit `dataChanged(const QModelIndex& topLeft, const QModelIndex& bottomRight)` whenever these types need redrawing.  It gets worse with interactive content because you would need to force an update on mouse overs in order to trigger the delegate painting.

For stuff like this you are better off using `QGraphicsScene/View`.  Rather than rely on a model, each item can take of itself and you still get only essential repaints (via it's BSP structure), plus you have the option of hardware acceleration.